# converting (roughly) the current time into a 32 bit integer

Tags: c++

I just need a way to roughly convert current time into a 32 bit integer. It doesn't need to be very accurate.. even accuracy of only a couple minutes would be ok.

The main idea is the next time I need to check it, it should be higher than or at least not lower than the previous time I retrieved this value. (I don't check very often)

I use C++ 20 (the MSVC version of it, whatever comes with VS 2022)

Comment: Did `std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()` not work for you? Or even `time()`?

Comment: Do you have to use a 32 bit integer?  The unix timestamp is a 64 bit integer that increases by one for each second since `1/1/1970`

Comment: _"the next time I need to check it, it should be higher than or at least not lower than the previous time"_ Then you don't mean "wall clock time", correct?  Those clocks on the wall sometimes move backwards.  Does the time on a _new run_ of your program need to be greater than the times from _last run_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use C++ 20 (the MSVC version of it, whatever comes with VS 2022)

Excellent.  This means that you have very good tools to work with in the chrono department.

Because of your requirements, there are only a few solutions I would consider acceptable.

- You *should not* deal in local time as it jumps around too much due to daylight saving or other political decisions.  You should only deal with UTC.
- You should not track time with precision finer than seconds.  You could track time in minutes, but seconds will do, and be considerably more responsive.
- Because of your 32 bit storage requirements, you should not use the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  This will overflow signed 32 bit storage in 2038, which is only 16 years from now.  16 years may seem like a long time.  But software has a way of lasting a long time.  You want to set your time bombs for long after your grandchildren have lived a good long life.
- I recommend a signed 32 bit integer vs unsigned so that subtraction larger from smaller will get you a negative amount, instead of wrapping to a large positive.  However if you want to use unsigned, you can double your range, and it is a simple change in the code.

Here is a small function that meets these requirements.

```
#include <chrono>

// seconds since 2020
int
get_current_time()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    constexpr sys_days epoch = 2020y/1/1;
    auto now = floor<seconds>(system_clock::now());
    return static_cast<int>((now - epoch)/1s);
}
```

This will give you seconds since 2020, and will not overflow until the year 2088.  It would also be easy for a future maintenance programmer to adjust the epoch 60 years from now.

The variable `now` holds a count of seconds since the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  However it is held in signed 64 bit storage which won't overflow until well after the sun turns into a red giant.

The expression `(now - epoch)/1s` subtracts off the epoch, giving you 64 bit `std::chrono::seconds` since 2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  Dividing that by `1s` gives you a signed 64 bit integral type without changing the value.  `(now - epoch()).count()` would do the same thing.  Use whichever expression you like better.

Finally just `static_cast` that signed 64 bit integral type to whatever your desired 32 bit integral type is.

Answer (score 1):

Using the C standard library - which is also part of the C++ standard library - you can use [std::time()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time)

The example in cppreference gives:

```cpp
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result))
              << result << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
```

Resulting in

```
Thu Oct  6 16:16:31 2022
1665072991 seconds since the Epoch
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/v1aE9rjfs

HOWEVER this time CAN warp back, meaning that you can get a number later that is smaller than the current one.

What you can do is to use [std::chrono::steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock).

But if you do not mind being specific to clang and gcc and Intel, you can use a builtin to read the TSC counter to get a simple and super fast solution

```
uint64_t now64 = __builtin_ia32_rdtsc();
uint32_t now = now64 >> 20;
```

Using the right 20 shift will give you one tick at roughly 3 milliseconds.  Note this counter will roll over in about 150 days.

Comment: the equivalent to `__builtin_ia32_rdtsc` in MSVC is `__rdtsc`

Comment: @phuclv I believe that is also available on gcc/clang but you might have to include a header